# Extract email id from a field having multiple words in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql -mytable.

Column Name:ResidenceAddress1

It has values like this:

```
sap3200@gmail.com,Rourkela
sap3212@gmail.com 2nd street,7 hils
2nd street, sap3212@gmail.com
```

I've tried this way:

```
select (case when substring_index(Residence_Address1, ' ', 1) like '%@%'
         then substring_index(Residence_Address1, ' ', 1) 
         else substring_index(Residence_Address1, ' ', -1)
     end) as email, Residence_Address1
from mytable
where Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal1=""
```

But its not giving me only email ids. How do I get only email ids from multiple words?

Comment: what do you mean email id?

Comment: means email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your sample data, here is a solution:

```
select 
    concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(ResidenceAddress1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)), '@gmail.com') as mail
    ,ResidenceAddress1
from mytable
```

This answer is based on your email is all `gmail.com` and your separator is space.

***Edited:***

`substring_index(ResidenceAddress1, '@', '1')` will get you this:

```
sap3200
sap3212
2nd street, sap3212
```

then

`substring_index('sap3200', ' ', -1) => sap3200`
`substring_index('sap3212', ' ', -1) => sap3212`
`substring_index('2nd street, sap3212', ' ', -1) => sap3212`

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfed4f/7)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I get bit confused with this 1 and -1 in substring_index. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: But I am facing the problem in updating the record.

Comment: I need your help again.1)it merges wrong id. eg. sap100@yahoo.com,sap3212@gmail.com. It merges like this - sap100@gmail.com 2)When there is a full residence address along with email, it fetches full address in mail column. eg. 21,Sunflower, M.C.Street,zipcode,cityname,email-sap3212@gmail.com. I tried this way:select concat(substring_index((substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', 2)),'@gmail',1),'@gmail.com') as mail, residence_address1
from fulldata_table
where Residence_Address1!="" and Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%'  . This also gives full address, but it didn't merge wrong way.

Comment: I ultimately want to fetch all emails from residence_address field.

Comment: Please ask a new question on SO.

Comment: I've posted it. I think there was no need for a new question. Anyways.

Comment: @iks_in I've answer that question as well. Let's do this there.